# Angular: What is the best way for storing objects in service for showing in view and crud functions to server

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I want to create a service that gets relational data from the server. I have two options in mind but I'm torn on which one to choose.

First option is to return the data in a multidimensional array of objects.

```
posts = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample 1', comments: [{id: 1, message:  'Sample comment 1', replies: [{id: 1, message: 'Sample reply 1'}]}]}]
```

Second option is to return a one dimensional array for each objects.

```
posts = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample ', comment_id: 1}]
comments = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample comment 1', reply_id: 1}]
replies = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample reply 1'}]
```

and compare each object arrays by their foreign and primary keys

I don't know which one is much better or if there's other way of doing this in angular. What I want is to easily add edit delete data to the server as well as to easily update or for example push a new data on the object for the view.

Comment: That is not looking Good Data structure Post Must be an Object in that you need to use comments and Replies as Sub nodes of Object which can Sort out your issue . if you wanna use same DS to continue You need to Process all these json arrays and then convert it as Object

Comment: Aren't  my examples objects inside an array? Based on what I understand on your answer, I think it's more like with the first option. But can you give an example to be more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the second option, but changing the structure so the objects point to their parent, not to their child:

```
posts = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample '}]
comments = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample comment 1', post_id: 1}]
replies = [{id: 1, message: 'Sample reply 1', comment_id: 1}]
```

This allows you to build structures with multiple children that link to a single parent.

The advantages here are that the objects are like NoSQL responses.  This gives you some flexibility on the database.

Also, you can wait until you need then before requesting them.  If you display a list of posts that are clickable, then clicking on one would request the comments for that post (and likewise with the replies).  This would reduce the overhead of downloading all the posts, comments and replies in a single request, and only download the objects as they are clicked.

Comment: Thanks. Yes my mistake with the id's. So everytime I go to a new post, I need to fetch for the comments and replies for that post? What if I go to another post then go back to this post? It would still fetch for the comments and replies? I was thinking if there's a way to prevent frequent request to the server?

Comment: You can cache the data by id, and only fetch new data when it's not in the cache.

Comment: I see, last question, do i need to make a service for each objects? postService, commentService and replyService? then for each service, I'll return the posts from the server? It's really confusing for me about how to fetch data in angular. I have two pages that shows posts from the server, different posts for different pages. I also thought of create services PER module. so one "postModule1Service" for one page and another "postModule2Service" for the other page. or should this be handled per scope of controller? Any ideas?

Comment: That would be the AngularJS way of handling objects, to create a service for each collection of objects.  If the data source is RESTful, use the $resource module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I see. I'll check this out. However, it gets into my head that I need to fetch ALL of the data per collection. For example, I have this post, then get all the comments for that post, then get the replies for each comments, then how do I get the users for each of these comments and replies? I'm trying to list posts from the database with their respective comments and replies all at once and show it without having to fetch data again from the server.

Comment: You haven't shown your method of fetching data, so that would be another question.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help! Really appreciate it! @brent-washburne